# Add cron job on startup from a script

Tags: cron, scripts

I would like to add a command to be run at startup from within a shell script.

For example, I run the script once and it adds the cron job, so from that time on, each time the OS starts, a specific program is started.

More specific, I'd need `xbindkeys` to run on startup and this to be done by a one-time running script.

So far I think this line would do the work:

```
@reboot xbindkeys
```

(`xbindkeys` is in PATH)

How could I add this job from a script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1135/114274) for more details. Adding `@reboot xbindkeys` to your crontab would work, but apparently only works when the machine is *rebooted* not when it comes up cold.

```
sudo echo '@reboot xbindkeys' >> /etc/crontab
```

That will add the line to your cron jobs, but typically I call the script by adding it in a line to `/etc/init.d/rc.local`, though I like Riccardo's suggestion of adding it to ~/.gnomerc.

Answer (score 1):

Use `crontab -e` to edit a user's crontab (A list of startup scripts that users have added).
Add following line at the end:

```
@reboot <command>
```

Examples:

- `@reboot my_script.sh`
- `@reboot python my_script.py arg_1 arg_2`

Finally use `crontab -l` to make sure your script was added to the list.